# get back recent locations option in nautilus save as dialog

Tags: nautilus, 17.04, dialog

I'm currently using Ubuntu 17.04 and I realized that the "recent locations" options is no longer available in the "save as" dialog, neither in nautilus.

I'm using the nautilus version 3.20.4 that comes with ubuntu.

Is there some way to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pressing Alt+r? That brings recent in my Ubuntu-Mate 17.04.